# How to access individual characters of an array of strings correctly?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I'm new to c, and I don't yet understand well enough array structures. I've been struggling for the past hour with finding a way to get nth character of the kth string within an array, and I still don't get it. I have no idea why it shows me everything beyond the nth character, when I just want it to show that nth char.

I've checked [How do I access an individual character from an array of strings in c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606879/how-do-i-access-an-individual-character-from-an-array-of-strings-in-c)
, and I still can't get it to work.

```
char ch[3][10] = {"Str 1", "Str 2", "Str 3"};
char a[10][10];    
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    strcpy(a[i], ch[i]);
    printf("a[%d]: \"%s\"\n", i, &a[i]);
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        printf("a[%d][%d]: \"%s\"\n", i, j, &a[i][j]);
    }
```

What the output is (nth char + everything beyond):

```
a[0]: "Str 1"
a[0][0]: "Str 1"
a[0][1]: "tr 1"
a[0][2]: "r 1"
a[0][3]: " 1"
a[0][4]: "1"
a[1]: "Str 2"
a[1][0]: "Str 2"
a[1][1]: "tr 2"
a[1][2]: "r 2"
a[1][3]: " 2"
a[1][4]: "2"
a[2]: "Str 3"
a[2][0]: "Str 3"
a[2][1]: "tr 3"
a[2][2]: "r 3"
a[2][3]: " 3"
a[2][4]: "3"
```

What I want the output to be (the nth char):

```
a[0][0]: "S"
a[0][1]: "t"
a[0][2]: "r"
a[0][3]: " "
a[0][4]: "1"
...
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%s` is used for printing strings. An individual character is not a string, it's a `char`, you print it with `%c`.

You also don't use `&` when passing arguments to `printf()` (unless you're trying to print a pointer to a variable rather than the variable itself).

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    strcpy(a[i], ch[i]);
    printf("a[%d]: \"%s\"\n", i, a[i]);
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        printf("a[%d][%d]: \"%c\"\n", i, j, a[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the line

```
strcpy(a[i], ch[i]);
```

`strcpy` is used to copy strings (or an array of chars, that's the full name of it)
The way you can access each individual character is by saying `ch[i]`

**Full explanation:**
Every string hides an extra character in the end. That is `\0`, the "escape sequence character" This is used so that the compiler knows when the string ends in the memory.
The way `strcpy` works is by looping and copying each character in the string, until it reaches the end of the string (when it sees the `\0`).